# How to apply video effects to a native app in osx

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, opengl

I understand the notion of applying filters to images using APIs. However, in regards to an app like [Cathode](http://www.secretgeometry.com/apps/cathode/), which is a terminal abstraction I guess, how does one go about creating such an app?

How would you explain how such an app could be created from a high level point of view.

For example, for image filters I could say, in your MVC cocoa app your controller implements an image API, which might load the image to memory, apply a filter to it though some methods calls, and then I send the response to a view.

but with something like Cathode, is it even an MVC cocoa app? Are there filters being applied to some view?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from eyeballing the front page of the Cathode [sales site](http://www.secretgeometry.com/apps/cathode/), I would guess that their application breaks down more-or-less like this:

- The application is a Cocoa application in which the main UI component is some a custom `NSView` use for OpenGL rendering, as discussed in Apple's documentation.  This [direct link](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_drawing/opengl_drawing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001987-CH404-SW2) might break, but the following search terms will likely land you there: `custom nsview opengl`.
- The fonts are probably not the system fonts, but some custom bitmapped fonts.
- The terminal text is rendered to an FBO with an attached color texture.
- The texture is filtered using either a fragment shader, or using OpenCL via CL/GL sharing.
- The texture is deformed by applying the texture not to a straight-up single quad, but by pasting it to a mesh, which is deformed.  This produces the bendy / tube effect in the screenshot.

That's about it.  It *is* an MVC Cocoa app, and it probably *is* using filters.

Comment: [Core Image](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/) is also a helpful technology in this situation.

Comment: + wow great answer James, thanks. So, essentially, most of the magic is happening in this custom view, and then the majority of the programming bypasses the cocoa API and talks directly to OpenGL, which is a bit closer to the metal and uses graphic specific terms like mesh, texture, and shaders?

Comment: Likely, yes.  Cocoa just binds it all together for display, but the cool stuff is probably mostly GL code.  But as andy pointed out above, CoreImage is capable of some cool filters, too.  It's possible that they are using that for some of the work.  I'm still betting on GL, but without buying the application and disassembling, I cannot say for sure.